# HOTP key generator in Swift not returning same value as in Java

Tags: java, swift

I am trying yo generate a secret key in Swift3, with the same algorithm as used in Java.

This is the code in Java:

```
private int createKey()
{
long steps = 15041892;

 // Put steps value into byte array
     byte[] buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(Long.SIZE / Byte.SIZE).putLong(Long.reverseBytes(steps)).array();

     //Encode with HMACSHA256   
      Key sk = new SecretKeySpec(buffer, HASH_ALGORITHM);
      Mac mac = null;

        try {
            mac = Mac.getInstance(sk.getAlgorithm());
            mac.init(sk);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        byte[] hashDevId = mac.doFinal(("fcd5dc0295c5e3e").getBytes());

    //Take the least 4 significant bits of H and use it as an offset, O.
        int bCodeDevId = Truncate(hashDevId);

    //The token is the lowest N digits of I in base 10.If the result has fewer digits than N, pad it with zeroes from the left.
        //Reduction modulo 10^Digit
        int keyDevId = bCodeDevId % (int) Math.pow(10, 8);

return keyDevId;
}
private int Truncate(byte[] hash)
{
    int truncationOffset = hash[hash.length - 1] & 0xF;

    int binaryCode = ((hash[truncationOffset] & 0x7F) << 24) |
            ((hash[truncationOffset + 1] & 0xFF) << 16) |
            ((hash[truncationOffset + 2] & 0xFF) << 8) |
            (hash[truncationOffset + 3] & 0xFF);

    return binaryCode;
}
```

While in Swift I use OTPGenerator, that is based on the same logic. Below is the main function used.

```
func generateOTPForCounter(_ counter: UInt64) -> String? {
counter = 15041892
self.secretKey = "fcd5dc0295c5e3e".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!

    var newCounter = counter.bigEndian

    let counterData = Data(bytes: &newCounter, count: MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: newCounter))

    var bigEndian = counter.bigEndian
    let count = MemoryLayout<UInt64>.size
    let bytePtr = withUnsafePointer(to: &bigEndian) {
        $0.withMemoryRebound(to: UInt8.self, capacity: count) {
            UnsafeBufferPointer(start: $0, count: count)
        }
    }
    let byteArray = Array(bytePtr)

    let algorithm: CCHmacAlgorithm = self.algorithm.algorithm //CCHmacAlgorithm(kCCHmacAlgSHA256)

    let hashPtr = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: Int(self.algorithm.hashLength)) //CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH

    defer { hashPtr.deallocate(capacity: Int(self.algorithm.hashLength)) }

    self.secretKey.withUnsafeBytes { secretBytes in
        counterData.withUnsafeBytes { counterBytes in
            CCHmac(algorithm, secretBytes, self.secretKey.count, counterBytes, counterData.count, hashPtr)
        }
    }



    let hash = Data(bytes: hashPtr, count: Int(self.algorithm.hashLength))

    var truncatedHash = hash.withUnsafeBytes { (ptr: UnsafePointer<UInt8>) -> UInt32 in
        let offset = ptr[hash.count - 1] & 0x0f
        let truncatedHashPtr = ptr + Int(offset)
        return truncatedHashPtr.withMemoryRebound(to: UInt32.self, capacity: 1) {
            $0.pointee
        }
    }
    truncatedHash = UInt32(bigEndian: truncatedHash)
    truncatedHash = truncatedHash & 0x7fffffff

    let pinValue = truncatedHash % UInt32(self.pinModeTable[self.pinLength])

    return String(format: "%0*u", self.pinLength, pinValue) //self.pinLength = 8
}
```

As a result in Swift I get this value for the key 01019962, while in Java 94966159

Thanks in advance.